Gnome apps on KDE Plasma break cursor
I switched to Arch Linux running KDE Plasma and whenever I run a Gnome app like nautilus, the cursor size is not right. I tried this for other Gnome apps too and all of them have the same issue. Here is a picture:

For some reason the gnome sound recorder does not have the issue anymore. I fixed this by installing it from the discover app and removing the normal version. I tried this for other apps too but it doesn't work.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
